# Efficient way to delete millions of rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete, delete-row, sql-execution-plan

I'm new to PostgreSQL, so I would be thankful for your help.

I need to delete over 10 millions rows from table which has about 20 millions rows. Because first 4 millions have some dependencies, I want to delete the ones without any dependencies (in my case, rows with id over 3999999).

I have tried this:

```
DELETE FROM public.orders
    WHERE public.orders.id > 3999999;
```

And so I have tried this one:

```
BEGIN;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE DELETE FROM public.orders
    WHERE public.orders.id > 3999999;
ROLLBACK;
```

Unluckily, it takes eternity to execute it in both cases! Could you give me any advice to make it more efficient?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe you could have an index on the public.orders table for the id column.

Comment: You should consider to generate a new table and then delete the old one.

Comment: @McNets But, please, how to do it if ID's of 4 millions rows in this table are used as foreign keys in other tables? :-)

Comment: The time is probably spent on checking the other tables's FK constraints. Do you have indexes on these FKs? (you **really** should)

Comment: If you're sure that there are no constraints on the rows you want to delete then `alter table orders disable trigger all` before the delete then `alter table orders enable trigger all` after.

Comment: Thanks for your advices! I see deleting such an amount of rows is not a usual use case. So I have just deleted two smaller tables and the big one, re-created them and filled them with data using scripts (which I have had written, so it was a quick process).